# DVORAK EN-GB layout on a german laptop keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dvorak

Would it be possible to use a dvorak keyboard layout with UK punctuation on a german laptop keyboard? I'm planning to buy a new Dell laptop but they won't sell me one with a UK English keyboard. I've compared the keys between this new one and my current laptop and they are in identical positions, just with different labels. I'm pretty sure it is possible to do this but I would like some confirmation :) I'm using (Ubuntu) Linux.

[UK keyboard](http://imageshack.us/a/img197/6559/ueal.JPG)

[German keyboard](http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_IMG_9611_90ac1fe032.jpg)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which OS(es) are you asking about?

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's likely.  I can confirm that EN-**US** Dvorak works on German laptop keyboards in Windows XP and Ubuntu, so I assume the UK variant would not be so different as to not work, same for the newer OS versions you probably plan to use.

Comment: Thanks! I'm mainly worried about whether the keys map the same in the UK and German layouts (so that switching between my old and new laptop is painless). If you don't have any problem with a US layout, I guess I shouldn't either. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use any keyboard layout on any keyboard, and it isn't limited to your physical keyboard. But do note that special characters can switch around, and that some are based on QWERTY, QWERTZ or AZERTY layouts.